# Multiple parent categories

Tags: categories, multisite

I'm new to wordpress. I want to create some main categories and 5 sub categories for each main category. Sub categories will be same for both main categories. E.g main categories will be "USA","Canada" etc. sub categories will be "places","photos" etc. Is it possible to make this with single wordpress or do i need to install another wordpress for each main category?

Comment: you may want to also consider using *multiple taxonomies*, not just one- categories. one taxonomy for location, another taxonomy for content type, then you won't have duplication of sub-categories. [see taxonomies in codex for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

Comment: This is exactly what i need, thanks. If you post it as answer i will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to also consider using multiple taxonomies, not just one- categories. One taxonomy for location, another taxonomy for content type, then you won't have duplication of sub-categories. [see taxonomies in codex for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, just create these categories from the categories menu in wordpress. Though, you need to create main categories and then subcategories within each. Thats how wordpress works by default.

So you create two categories

"USA" and "Canada"

and then create  "places" and "photos" twice and then select different parents each time.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Manage_Categories_SubPanel

So you don't need multiple wordpress installations.

Comment: That's just stupid. Yes it works for small use cases, but would absolutely be failure and time consuming on dynamically large hierarchies

Comment: I realise that now why not share your own solution? I may solve it in a better way now using some custom taxonomy stuff but it would be great for learning if you could share yours.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a reliable solution yet. Once found, I'll absolutely share it here,